# Using LoadBitmap doesn't keep alpha channel in image

Tags: c#, alpha

I am trying to load some images from an unmanaged file and running into problems with the alpha not coming through. I have found that I can restore the alpha channel by doing this:

```
BitmapData bmData = 
    bmpSource.LockBits(
        new Rectangle(0, 0, bmpSource.Width, bmpSource.Height),
        ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, bmpSource.PixelFormat);

Bitmap dstBitmap = 
    new Bitmap(bmData.Width, bmData.Height, bmData.Stride,
    PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb, bmData.Scan0);

bmpSource.UnlockBits(bmData);
```

This works great when the desktop is set to 32bit colour, but for some reason when the desktop is set to 16bit colour, bmpSource is only a 16bit colour image, even though the source image in the resource file is actually a 32bit image with an alpha channel. How can I load these images as 32bit images with the alpha channel intact? Is there an unmanaged way to handle this instead of relying on the C# Bitmap class?

Comment: It might be helpful if you say the file format. For instance, if they're pngs you can always use libpng as a worst case scenario. Heck, depending on the format, writing your own loader wouldn't be too difficult considering the file format is usually floating around publicly.

Comment: I'm trying to load RT_BITMAP resources from external applications.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I know that the Image class (which the Bitmap class is a sub class of), doesn't support Bitmap alpha transparency (they suggest using PNGs or GIFs instead). The bad news is you're going to have to create your own bmp loader or find one out there (the one I used back in my C++ days seems to be dead and gone now or I'd link to it). The good news is that it's pretty easy to create your own: [File Format](http://www.fileformat.info/format/bmp/corion.htm)

Comment: I ended up creating my own bitmap loader in the end. Unfortunately it seemed to be the only way to handle this, luckily the bitmap spec is fairly simple.